# html print table add total value as footer per page

Tags: javascript, html, table-footer

Is there a way to print a table that includes total value of a column in a page

For example:

```
*Page 1*  
Name | Salary 
Gray | 1500  
Red  | 2000  
Total| 3500 

*Page 2* 
Name | Salary 
Black| 500
White| 2000
Total| 2500
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please add a relevant code snippet of what you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `JavaScript`. Implement your logic in a `function` that sets the value of *Total* to the sum of the rest. Also, post your code so we have more information about what you do and how you approach the issue.